# eager loading nested object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models like below

**Customer.rb**

```
has_many :appointments
has_many :addresses
has_many :contacts
```

**Address.rb**

```
belongs_to :customer
```

**Contact.rb**

```
belongs_to :customer
```

**Appointment.rb**

```
belongs_to :customer
```

I have defined API's to return customers like below but with one extra attribute i.e appointment_id.

```
customers: [
  {
    appointment_id: 'xxxxxxx'
    ..
    ..
    ..
    addresses: [{...}, {...}]
    contacts: [{...},{...}]
  },
  {
    ..
  },
  .....

]
```

The above api is defined in a way that I pass *@customers* (which is array of customers along with their nested objects address, contacts). Problem is How should write active record query to return so so data.

***Current Approach:***

*// I got list of appointment id's and I  should return corresponding customers data as shown in above api.*

```
cust_ids    = Appointment.where(blah blah blah).pluck(:customer_id)
@customers =  Customer.where(appointment_id: cust_ids).includes(:addresses, :contacts)
```

**What I want?**

My above approach doesnt have appointment_id in @customers object. How should I get it? Do I need to join table
   along with includes. ??

Comment: Well how you will you handle multiple `appointment_id` in your JSON. As a customer may have multiple appointment ids but i can't see a valid JSON for this behaviour

Comment: @NimishGupta  initially i am fetching set of appointment_ids then i am fetching correspondin customers. So, in these customers data I want that appointment_id  as well

Comment: what will happen if a customer has 2 appointments?
what will be the JSON in that case?
Please let me know the answer to this question so that I can try to help you out

Comment: @NimishGupta In my case customer will have single appointment in a day and in controller action appointment will be single for each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add inverse of to association definitions to avoid n+1 during preload

```
# customer.rb
has_many :appointments, inverse_of: :customer

# appointment
belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :appointment
```

Now you can fetch your appointments from the DB and construct JSON

```
# in the controller
appointments = Appointment.where(blah blah blah)
  .preload(customer: [:contacts, :addresses])

customers = appointments.map do |appointment|
  appointment.customer
   .as_json(include: [:contacts, :addresses])
   .merge(appointment_id: appointment.id)
end

render json: { customers: customers }
```

Comment: The inverse of `belongs_to customer` is `appointments` (plural), but `inverse_of` isn't necessary here as the [automatic inverse detection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can think of

```
appointment_ids = Appointment.where(blah blah blah).pluck(:id)
customers = Customer.includes(:addresses, :contacts, :appointments).where(appointments: { id: appointment_ids })
```

Now when you will write

`customers.first.appointments` you will only get those appointments which satisfy the first condition.

And According to your say, it will have only one appointment per customer per day.

So you can do `customers.first.appointments.first.id`

Comment: You misunderstood question. I got list of appointment id's and I should return corresponding customers data along with that appointment_id. Not first appointment of customer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `select` in the query:

cust_ids    = Appointment.where(blah blah blah).pluck(:customer_id)
@customers =  Customer.where(appointment_id: cust_ids).includes(:addresses, :contacts).select("customers.*")